# Is it possible to mute the Allays?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I love having them around me, but after 1 hour, their jiggling gets old very quick, and now I want to mute them, is this possible?

[Allay wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Allay)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute the following command to silence all allays:

```
execute as @e[type=allay] run data merge entity @s {Silent:1b}
```

Edit:
You could execute the command continuously with a repeating command block or inside a function of a [datapack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_pack). In the latter case I would modify the command for performance reasons to this

```
execute as @e[type=allay,tag=!Silenced] run data merge entity @s {Silent:1b}
tag @e[type=allay,tag=!Silenced] add Silenced
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, it works, but I wanted to only mute their jiggling, I want to still hear when they pickup and deliver things :), is there any way to excecute this command everythime I log in? I accept this as an answer for now

Comment: I like this solution because it affects the actual values in server so also other players can't hear it

Comment: thanks @IceFreez3r you are adding a tag for easy search, is it possible instead to just search for data value?, I am new into minecraft commands, but as a software engineer, I can understand how tags may be faster than digging into a dictionary

Comment: I add a tag to mark the allay as silenced, such that it wont be modified in the next ticks again and again.

Answer (score 3):

#### You could use the "Extreme Sound Muffler" mod it has a [Forge version](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/extreme-sound-muffler) and a [Fabric version](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/extreme-sound-muffler-fabric-official/).

It allows you to control the volume/mute every single individual sound, so this should allow you to just mute the "jiggling" and not the gifting sounds.

Slight disclaimer: I've never used this mod, it's just in a lot of modded packs I've played

Comment: oh awesome, gonna try it

Comment: this works great, the sound I wanted to mute is `entity.allay.ambient_with_item:minecraft`, unfortunately I can't select 2 answers as accepted, thanks for the mod link!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can turn the friendly creatures sound to a low level. This worked in my case unless you specifically want the allay to be muted.

Comment: yeah just the allay, this is what I ended up doing for now

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found so far, but sometimes it also mutes doors and other sounds, but it works silencing the allays, I hope somebody have an alternative answer.

https://www.planetminecraft.com/texture-pack/mute-allay-pack/